# Ubuntu would not start

Tags: boot

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 for quite a while now and yesterday I wanted to change my python version while following a tutorial (unfortunately I do not remember the name of the site). The only thing I remember is that after entering a specific command (which was a step in the tutorial) not only python but all other files had started to get deleted. I tried to terminate the operation but nothing helped so I decided to turn off the computer. When I tried to turn it on again Ubuntu did not start and the computer was stuck on a default greeting screen (A screen which shows up for a second before the os starts up).

After I had encountered this problem I entered the BIOS and my Ubuntu os was still present in the start-up options.

My question is: it there some way to restore my previous os? Or I need to install Ubuntu again?

(I had already prepared a bootable USB)

Comment: Python is the heart of Ubuntu many features depend on it. You have broken it beyond repair. Time to re install. Why did you remove it?

Comment: I guess out of frustration... I have been working on a python project but encountered problems with a particular python library that I really needed (It was not compatible with the version that I had). I had tried many solutions but none of them worked, at that point I was pretty annoyed because I had already spent a lot of time on this so I tried brute forcing the problem by reinstalling python. Mistakes were made I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tampering with the standard python version of Ubuntu is a fatal error. You need to reinstall.

Boot a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.